# window.matchMedia listener not triggering

Tags: javascript, css

I have noticed a strange bug, which I was wondering if anyone else has encountered or can shed any light as to what I might be doing wrong.

I am using window.matchMedia to monitor/detect if the orientation of a page changes. I also have some separate css in a media query. However when I have a media query in the css which is the same as the one I am trying to listen to in the js it doesn't seem to trigger.

Here is the js code I am using

```
var current_orientation = 'unknown';
var orientation_match = window.matchMedia("(orientation:portrait)");

orientation_match.addListener( function (match) { 

    if(match.matches)
    {
        current_orientation = 'portrait';
    }
    else
    {
        current_orientation = 'landscape';
    }

    console.log('Orientation updated: ' + current_orientation);

});

if(orientation_match.matches)
{
    current_orientation = 'portrait';
}
else
{
    current_orientation = 'landscape';
}

console.log('Orientation: ' + current_orientation);
```

This works fine, but as soon as I add the following to my css, it then doesn't trigger the listener code.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

    header
    {
        height: 60px;
    }

}
```

Comment: What browser and device you are using?

Comment: I am using Chrome on my MacOS - but the code is actually for a Cordova app and it has the same problem

Comment: Idk if Chrome for OS X supports orientation, but just tested on Safari iOS 6 and found no issues: http://jsbin.com/AYABAbo/1/edit?css,js,output